# Excel Number Formatting

Tags: excel

I'm currently working on a sheet that contains part numbers in it.  I'd like them to be formatted like this:

```
@@@@-#####-XX
```

Where @s can be letters or numbers, #s are numbers, and Xs are letters.

I run into two problems while doing this.  The first is that I can't figure out how to handle text and numbers at the same time in the Custom Format dialog box.  The second is that occasionally a part number will have 3 letters after the second hyphen rather than 2, and I can't figure out how I should structure the condition to differentiate between the two formats.

How can I handle numbers and text at the same time when creating a custom format, and how can I add the condition described above (based on character numbers or something)?

Thanks.

Comment: Do the part numbers already exist or are you trying to generate them? Also, what is it that you need to do with them?

Comment: According to the documentation this should work: AAAA\-#####\-LL But I get the error that Excel cannot use it :( http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/input-mask-syntax-and-examples-HP005187550.aspx

Comment: @ChrisProsser the numbers already exist, but not in the sheet.  I just want to be able to avoid typing a hyphen whenever I enter them into the sheet.

Comment: @MrFox I got the same error you did.  I think that maybe Access might have some functionality that excel doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If can't be achieved with custom formatting then a formula such as below may suit:

```
 =LEFT(A1,4)&"-"&MID(A1,5,5)&"-"&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-9)
```

Comment: This does the trick as far as the formatting goes.  However it requires 2 columns (one with the entry and one with the formatted string).  Is there any way to do the same type of thing in one column?

Comment: That sounds like the best plan of attack.  Thanks very much for the formula!

Answer (score 0):

If the middle number section has to be 5 digits, use

@-0000#-XX

But I don't think number formats are designed to handle Alphanumeric entries, and I can't help you with those X's